# how to compare strings with ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the below code, i'm getting environments from localStorage which i had stored earlier and assigning it to $scope.environments. When the accessMethod is "A" then it should show button and when accessMethod is "B" it should show a dropdown.

```
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" name="loginForm" ng-controller="PostsCtrl"  novalidate ng-submit="Onsubmit()" >
                    <fieldset>
                        <ul class="heroes" ng-repeat="environment in environments   track by $index" >
                            <li ng-if="environment.accessMethod === 'A'">
                                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
                                    <span class="badge">{{environment.code}}</span> 
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-if="environment.accessMethod === 'B'">
                                <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown >
                                    <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle  ng-disabled="disabled">
                                        <span class="badge">{{environment.code}}</span> <span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" >
                                        <li   ng-repeat="roledetail in environment.roles"  
                                              ng-click="onSelect(roledetail.roleName)" >
                                            <a href="" >{{roledetail.roleName}}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>


                        </fieldset>
                </form>
```

$scope.environments = localStorage.getItem("environments");
I kept the Json for understanding but i'm accessing it through localStorage.

```
$scope.environments = [{
  "code": "abc",
  "name": null,
  "accessMethod": "A",
  "roles": [{
      "roleId": 1,
      "roleName": "A"
    },
    {
      "roleId": 3,
      "roleName": "B"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "code": "XYZ",
  "name": null,
  "accessMethod": "A",
  "roles": [{
      "roleId": 1,
      "roleName": "A"
    },
    {
      "roleId": 3,
      "roleName": "B"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "code": "Neo",
  "name": null,
  "accessMethod": "B",
  "roles": [{
      "roleId": 1,
      "roleName": "A"
    },
    {
      "roleId": 3,
      "roleName": "C"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "code": "LAB",
  "name": null,
  "accessMethod": "B",
  "roles": [{
      "roleId": 1,
      "roleName": "A"
    },
    {
      "roleId": 3,
      "roleName": "B"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: no error but it not displaying anything. When i assign $scope.environments through localStorage.get("environments").

Comment: you are not doing Json.parse when assigning to your $scope.

Comment: create a plunker or jsbin for your prob. may it help us to rectify where you are missing the flow.

Comment: It worked ...i wasn't parsing while assigning  to $scope @Hey24sheep thank you

Comment: I will create an answer so you can accept it. and close this question

Comment: @SabnekarRajnikant I have created an answer, if my answer solved your problem, please accept it to close your question. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing Json.parse when assigning to your scope.

Do this

```
$scope.environments = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("environments"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use ng-show instead of if. ng-show changes the visibility of an element on the fly whereas ng-if decides whether that element should even be rendered or not.

Comment: but comparatively using ng-if is more recommended than using ng-show.

Comment: Thats ok . But when i'm assigning $scope.environments = [{
  "code": "abc",
  "name": null,
  "accessMethod": "A",
  "roles": [{
      "roleId": 1,
      "roleName": "A"
    },
    {
      "roleId": 3,
      "roleName": "B"
    }
  ]
}]  its Displaying !!

Comment: @MohammedGadi the answer caters to the problem statement. Your comment just states the performance of two directives which is unrelated to the original question.